# XRDP immediately closes connection Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, xrdp

Every time I login on my arch linux server via rdp, it immediately kicks me off. The only error I see in logs is my window manager exited, but no details

What DE/WM I've tried:

```
lightdm/KDE
sddm/KDE
blackbox/KDE
enlightenement/kde

enlightenment/lxqt
lightdm/lxqt
```

Every time, instant I login, it kicks me off. Tried RDP over SSH and plain RDP to no avail.

Comment: Could you add the last few lines of ~/.xsession-errors?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani no such file, but I have a bunch of logs in my home directory from xrdp, here's one - https://transfer.sh/13IwEb/xrdp.log